# Dismissing a View Controller disorders View in root Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have performed segue from one view controller to another programmatically, whenever i press a button in second VC the VC is dismissed and and main VC appears. Thought desired VC appears, segmented control disappears and tableView in VC moves to the bottom of the main VC leaving space in middle. The segmented control and table view appear in right way at right position whenever I scroll over view. What is wrong with my approach I couldn't figure it out please help.

[image]

```
//Segue to the another VC
func checkListSegue() {
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vaccineCheckListVC = sb.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VaccineCheckListVC") as! VaccineCheckListVC
        presentViewController(vaccineCheckListVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

//return back to main VC 
@IBAction func submitVaccineList(sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: First VC]
[image: Second VC]

[image: First VC after dismissing 2nd VC]
[image: First VC finally when scrolled]

Comment: Check out your MainViewController - is there anything in ViewDidLoad? When you go back to your MainViewController, ViewDidLoad will NOT fire again

Comment: There is nothing which is related to view disappearing in ViewDidLoad of MainViewController. Actually view reappears while scrolling.

Comment: Then post your code for cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Use viewwillAppear method to showing somthing that you want when coming back to view.

Comment: One of the calculation was affecting the constraints. I just figured it out thank you for suggestions.